# Applescript - Check if Page Content of URLs List contain THIS_TEXT | Output all these URLs

Tags: shell, applescript

**Trying the following:**

1. My script returns approx. 20 URLs as variable Single_URLs
2. Check if these URLs contain THIS_TEXT
3. Keep URL's containing THIS_TEXT
4. Delete the other URLs from the result

Pure Applescript or Shell.

My example script just checks IF the provided URL contains THIS_TEXT as i could not get any further by now.

```
--Open Pages
set site_url to "https://teespring.com/shop/CLASSIC-DODGE-CHARGER-MOP?aid=marketplace&tsmac=marketplace&tsmic=search#pid=212&cid=5819&sid=front"
tell application "Safari"
    activate
    open location site_url
end tell

-- wait until page loaded
property testingString : "CLASSIC DODGE CHARGER" --Text on website to look for

set pageLoaded to false
tell application "Safari"
    repeat while pageLoaded is false
        set readyState to (do JavaScript "document.readyState" in document 1)
        set pageText to text of document 1

        if (readyState is "complete") and (pageText contains testingString) then set pageLoaded to true
        delay 0.2
    end repeat
end tell

-- get number of links
set theLinks to {}
tell application "Safari" to set num_links to (do JavaScript "document.links.length" in document 1)
set linkCounter to num_links - 1
-- retrieve the links
repeat with i from 0 to linkCounter
    tell application "Safari" to set end of theLinks to do JavaScript "document.links[" & i & "].href" in document 1


end repeat
theLinks
set nonExcludedURLs to {}
pageLoaded
```

This is a a charitable project to help Artists not being cheated. Every help is very welcome, Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a script that would do that with AppleScript:

```
use AppleScript version "2.4" -- Yosemite (10.10) or later
use scripting additions

on run
    set URLFoundItems to {}
    set SearchItemsList to {"CLASSIC DODGE CHARGER"}
    set URLList to {"https://teespring.com/shop/CLASSIC-DODGE-CHARGER-MOP?aid=marketplace&tsmac=marketplace&tsmic=search#pid=212&cid=5819&sid=front"}
    repeat with i from 1 to count of URLList
        set URLv to item i of URLList
        tell application "Safari"
            try
                tell window 1
                    set current tab to (make new tab with properties {URL:URLv})
                end tell
            on error
                make new document with properties {URL:URLv}
            end try
            set readyState to (do JavaScript "document.readyState" in document 1)
            set pageLoaded to false

            repeat while pageLoaded is false
                set readyState to (do JavaScript "document.readyState" in document 1)
                set SearchIn to source of document 1
                if (readyState is "complete") and SearchIn ≠ "" then
                    set pageLoaded to true
                else
                    delay 0.2
                end if
            end repeat


            repeat with z from 1 to count of SearchItemsList
                set SearchString to item z of SearchItemsList
                set x to offset of SearchString in SearchIn
                if x > 0 then
                    set URLFoundItems to URLFoundItems & URLv & " (" & SearchString & ")" as string
                end if
            end repeat
            tell window 1
                close current tab
            end tell
        end tell
    end repeat
    return URLFoundItems
end run
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: AMAZING! Thank you. I will have to change a few small bits but it does exactly what i was asking for :) Have a good day